# Why does my pylab animation slow down with each update?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to display a simple animation by calling `imshow` in a for loop. Here's a demo of my problem:

```
import pylab,time
images = [pylab.uniform(0,255,(50,50)) for _ in xrange(40)]
pylab.ion()
timings = []
for img in images:
  tic = time.time()
  pylab.imshow(img)
  pylab.draw()
  toc = time.time()
  timings.append(toc-tic)
pylab.clf()
pylab.plot(timings)
pylab.title('elapsed time per iteration')
pylab.ioff()
pylab.show()
```

Note that I generate the images before running the loop, and that the only parts I time are the `imshow` and `draw` functions. I'm getting results that look like this:
[image: Result of running my demo]

How can I avoid this slowdown?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Things are slowing down because you're adding more and more images and drawing them *all* each time.

Either 1) clear the plot between each image (In your case, `pylab.cla()`), or better yet 2) don't make a new image, just set the data of the existing image to the new data.

As an example of using `cla()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

images = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(40, 50, 50))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.show()
for image in images:
    ax.imshow(image)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ax.cla()
```

And as an example of just setting the data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

images = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(40, 50, 50))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(images[0])
fig.show()
for image in images[1:]:
    im.set_data(image)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

You'll notice that the second method is considerably faster.

Comment: `set_data()` instead of repeating `imshow()`s saved me literal hours of computing time, even though I was careful about re-using figure, axis and colorbar