# Matplotlib Animation: updating radial view limit for polar plot

Tags: animation, matplotlib, label, limits

I'm trying to create an animated polar plot that, where the radial view limit increases/decreases to accommodate the radius. The yaxis updates just fine if I set polar=False, but it doesn't work correctly for a polar axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def data_gen():
    t = data_gen.t
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 1000:
        cnt+=1
        t += 0.05
        yield t, 1.1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t) * np.exp(t/10.)
data_gen.t = 0

plt.rc ('grid', color='g', lw=1, ls='-')
plt.rc ('xtick', labelsize=15, color='b')
plt.rc ('ytick', labelsize=15, color='b')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.05, .90, .9, .08], polar=False, axisbg='#BFBFBF', xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.05, .05, .9, .8], polar=True, axisbg='k')
#ax = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,.8,.8], polar=False, axisbg='k')
line, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 2.2)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 140)
ax2.grid(1)
xdata, ydata = [], []
title = ax1.text (0.02, 0.5, '', fontsize=14, transform=ax1.transAxes)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    title.set_text ('')
    return line, title

def run(data):
    # update the data
    t,y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()

    if y >= ymax:
        ax2.set_ylim (ymin, 2*ymax)
        ax2.figure.canvas.draw()

    title.set_text ("time = %.3f, y(t) = 1.1 + sin(2*pi*t) + exp(t/10) = %.3f" % (t, y))
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line, title

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, init, blit=True, interval=100, repeat=False)
```

Actually, the view limit does adjust, but the tick labels stay the same. Inserting raw_input() after the canvas is redrawn reveals that everything is redrawn correctly, but then the tick labels revert back to what they were before. Stranger still, this doesn't occur until the update() function is called a second time and returns.

I didn't have this problem when I animated the plot the old way, by calling draw() repeatedly. But I'd rather do it the right way with the animation module, as the old way had performance problems (The above code block is only to demonstrate the problem, and isn't the actual program that I'm writing).

I should note that I'm still learning MPL, so I apologize if some of my terminology is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895698/updating-the-xaxis-values-using-matplotlib-animation/17903145#17903145 <- related, but not quite a duplicate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558096/animated-title-in-matplotlib/17562747#17562747 <- also related, but not quite a duplicate.

Comment: As I mentioned, I was doing it the manual redraw way, but moved to using the animation module because of slow performance. Again, this is with a larger program, not the example one shown above. If I turn blitting off, then I will lose the performance gain, as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `blit`, the background is saved in cache for fast draw, you can clear the cache when the axis range is changed, add `ani._blit_cache.clear()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def data_gen():
    t = data_gen.t
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 1000:
        cnt+=1
        t += 0.05
        yield t, 1.1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t) * np.exp(t/10.)
data_gen.t = 0

plt.rc ('grid', color='g', lw=1, ls='-')
plt.rc ('xtick', labelsize=15, color='b')
plt.rc ('ytick', labelsize=15, color='b')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.05, .90, .9, .08], polar=False, axisbg='#BFBFBF', xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.05, .05, .9, .8], polar=True, axisbg='k')
#ax = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,.8,.8], polar=False, axisbg='k')
line, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 2.2)
ax2.set_xlim(0, 140)
ax2.grid(1)
xdata, ydata = [], []
title = ax1.text (0.02, 0.5, '', fontsize=14, transform=ax1.transAxes)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    title.set_text ('')
    return line, title

def run(data):
    # update the data
    t,y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()

    if y >= ymax:
        ax2.set_ylim (ymin, 2*ymax)
        ani._blit_cache.clear() # <- add to clear background from blit cache
        title.set_text('') # <- eliminate text artifact in title
        ax2.figure.canvas.draw()

    title.set_text ("time = %.3f, y(t) = 1.1 + sin(2*pi*t) + exp(t/10) = %.3f" % (t, y))
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line, title

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, init, blit=True, interval=100, repeat=False)
```

Comment: Definitely, a hack, but perhaps the best solution available for now. Any idea why this doesn't need to be done with rectangular axes? 

Also, I did have one issue with your solution. As you can see, I've edited the code so that it has an animated title on a separate axes. After clearing the blit cache, it leaves an artifact title under the animated one. I fixed this by clearing the title before redrawing. I've added this to your answer.